# Adobe Acrobat like software for Linux to analyse PDF files

Tags: linux, pdf, web-development

I want manualy recreate the layout of client PDF files to HTML.
I need to know font size, type, color, line high for text blocks in PDF files. 
I don't need to edit PDF files.

I'm looking for an software like Adobe Acrobat (Editor not Reader) for Linux.

The Linux PDF software I use in the moment shows sometimes 1 instead of the correct font size and no unit (pt, px …). Is this a PDF specialty or a bug?

Comment: what about a pdf to html converter? Are you trying to make reflowable html from a pdf? Or fixed html layout?

Comment: Sorry, "to html" was a (mistakable) simplified description / I need qweb templates with placeholders for database entries / one part of a qweb template is html code / i could try  first use a converter for pdf to html and second manualy convert html to qweb / Did you know any useful converter, maybe for bootstrap code too?